# Synthesis of phenethyl alcohol from benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, synthesis, alcohols

How can I make phenethyl alcohol $(\ce{C6H5CH2CH2OH})$ from benzene?

I have got information that phenethyl alcohol is made from benzene by Friedel-Crafts reaction between benzene and ethylene oxide in the presence of aluminium trichloride as follows:

$$\ce{C6H6 + CH2CH2O + AlCl3 → C6H5CH2CH2OAlCl2 + HCl}$$

But I have no idea how it reacts and proceeds to work.

Can anyone help me understanding the mechanism of synthesis and reaction of making phenethyl alcohol from benzene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ce{AlCl3}$ is a Lewis acid and will bind to the oxygen of the ethylene oxide giving a species that functions as $\ce{[R2O-AlCl2]+}.$

This cationic species will be attacked at carbon by the electron-rich aromatic ring in much the same way as a standard Friedel-Crafts reaction intermediate generated from an alkyl halide to give $\ce{[Ph-CH2CH2-OAlCl2]+}.$ This then loses $\ce{HCl}$ to give $\ce{PhCH2CHOAlCl2}$ which is stable until aqueous workup which gives phenethyl alcohol.

Comment: I can understand well about the mechanism of making phenethyl alcohol and how it works as Friedel-crafts reaction with Lewis acid and and make alkyl benzene!