# How to convert benzyl alcohol to 2-phenylethanoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

> How can we convert **benzyl** **alcohol** to **2-phenylethanoic acid**?

This is what I have tried.
[image]

Can someone tell me whether this is correct because I am not sure about the second reaction.
In my textbook it is given that the following reaction takes place.
[image]
But I am not sure whether the reaction will take place if **R'** is replaced by **H**.

Also other methods to convert **benzene** to **2-phenylethanoic acid** are welcome.

Comment: The reaction of a silver carboxylate salt with an alkyl halide gives a ester, not really useful in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is to do the first step as you have drawn making benzyl chloride, then treat that with KCN (in DMSO  or use water/CH2Cl2 with a phase transfer catalyst) to give 2-phenyl acetonitrile then hydrolyse that with aqueous sulfuric acid as described in this Organic Syntheses procedure [here](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV1P0436)

To convert benzene to 2-phenylethanoic acid: benzene reacts with ethylene oxide under Friedel-Crafts conditions to give 2-phenylethanol (see this SE answer [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/117955/synthesis-of-phenethyl-alcohol-from-benzene)). This is readily oxidised to 2-phenylethanoic acid.

Comment: Is the method which I did correct?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Goes even better with a trace of DMF to catalyse it.

Comment: Certainly the formation of benzyl chloride will work but, as @Waylander has pointed out, silver formate will give an ester, benzyl formate. The use of a silver salt here is overkill because potassium or sodium formate would suffice.